# access .db file from assets in android

Tags: android

i have a .db file with 2MB of size. i put it in assets folder in my project. And wrote the code as follow.but i got exception no table exits.please help me How to access .db file without copying into /databases.

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("assets\\TDP.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
  //  db.execSQL("create table TD_ASSEMBLY(name Text,password Text);");
  Cursor cur = db.query("TD_ASSEMBLY", 
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
       cur.moveToFirst();
       while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
         String first= cur.getString(0); 
         String second=cur.getString(1);
         tx.append(first+"  "+second);
         cur.moveToNext();
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regular path to retrieve a file from assets. Use getAssets() instead.

The best option is to save it on first run to the database folder in your app. See my answer here: [The data disappear after moving the application on a real device in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168806/the-data-disappear-after-moving-the-application-on-a-real-device-in-android/6168936#6168936) and the link therein for an example.

Answer (score 0):

refer these links' answers to copy database from assets:

[adding your own SQLite database to an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819)

[Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326)